# Customize/override view size when using presentModalViewController

Tags: objective-c, view, modal-dialog

I'm using presentModalView to display a modal view in an iPad app when my app enters the active state:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {  
  myViewController vc = [[myViewController alloc] init];  
  vc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;  
  vc.modalTransistionStyle = UImdoalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;  
  [self.window.rootViewController presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES];  
}
```

It functions fine, however myViewController is only 320 X 340, yet it gets displayed as a much larger view.   Is there anyway to customize or override the view size when using presentModalViewController?   Or is there some way other than presentModalViewController to display a modal view?

Answer (score 6):

You could do this by resizing the view.superview.frame like below:

```
vc.view.superview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 900, 700);
```

Comment: Thanks - This will work, but I ended up using the semi-modal approach discussed in this article.   http://ramin.firoozye.com/2009/09/29/semi-modal-transparent-dialogs-on-the-iphone/

Comment: Brian, where should I put this line? before or after the presenting? it doesn't work for me...